# Ansible docker_container module env file

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-container

I have an issue with the docker_container module for ansible (v2.3). When i try to pass the `env_file` properties in the playbook, I get the error :`no such file or directory`

```
---
- hosts: preprod-api
  become: yes
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - name: test configuration
      docker_container:
        name: "backend"
        image: "backend"
        state: started
        exposed_ports:
          - 80
        volumes:
          - /opt/application/i99/current/logs
        user: ansible
        env_file: 
          - "/opt/application/i99/current/backend/backend-PreProd-config.list"
```

I have tried with a file that exist on the ansible server and one on the target server with the same result.

here is the error :

```
`fatal: [my_hostname]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to my_hostname closed.\r\n", 
"module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):
    File \"/tmp/ansible_rySqS2/ansible_module_docker_container.py\", 
    line 2036, in <module>    main() File \"/tmp/ansible_rySqS2/ansible_module_docker_container.py\", 
    line 2029, in main\r\n    cm = ContainerManager(client)  File \"/tmp/ansible_rySqS2/ansible_module_docker_container.py\", 
    line 1668, in __init__\r\n    self.parameters = TaskParameters(client)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_rySqS2/ansible_module_docker_container.py\", 
    line 784, in __init__\r\n    self.env = self._get_environment()\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_rySqS2/ansible_module_docker_container.py\", 
    line 1134, in _get_environment\r\n    parsed_env_file = utils.parse_env_file(self.env_file)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/utils/utils.py\", 
    line 961, in parse_env_file with open(env_file, 'r') as f:\r\nIOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: \"['/path/to/my/file/that/exist/backend-PreProd-config.env']\"\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 0}`
```

So my question is, how can I pass the env file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

so i found the problem.
first the syntax is :

```
env_file: /local/dir/some/file.env
```

the file must be located on the target server and contain NO blank line or spaces in the first character.

Comment: Would be helpful if you show the environment variable file here.

Answer (score 1):

The `env_file` must be local to your host, and not a file inside the container.

```
env_file: 
      - "/local/dir/some/file.env"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried that but I get a "no such file or directory" error even when the file existe

Comment: @zeO_340, should this file be in docker container to get picked up?

Answer (score 0):

To add some useful information to the accepted answer.

Here is how you can write environment variable file.

### myfile.env

```css
USER=ElonMusk
PASSWORD=EV
DATABASE=Tesla
```